# C# method meaning

Tags: c#, syntax

so I am looking at this C# method

```
if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
            // Only runs in design mode
            _dataService.GetMachine(_machines[0].Machine.SerialNumber, (machine, error) => //<-- this is what I am confused about
            {
                SelectedMachine = new MachineViewModel(machine);
            });
        }
```

I understand the `if()` statement and the `SelectedMachine = new MachineViewModel(machine);` line.
But I am confused about the commented line.

`_dataService` calls a `GetMachine` method passing in `_machines[0].Machine.SerialNumber` param and `(machine, error) => {}`. It is not an "equal or less than" statement right?.
It kinda looks like a Javascript code to me...?

Does the method say,

```
If IsInDesignMode {
      dataservice.GetMachine(machine serial number, machine error is new MachineViewModel)
}
```

Can any one explain what `=> { }` this is? thank you very much!

Comment: Here's a couple of links for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: @RaymondChen Hi Raymond, yes you are right! I just clicked on the link. Thanks! i'll search stackoverflow even harder next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part you are asking about is an anonymous method that uses a lambda expression. It is commonly used in callbacks.

When you write this

```
(machine, error) => { SelectedMachine = new MachineViewModel(machine); }
```

you are making a function that has no name (and therefore cannot be reused by name, like a regular method). It is very convenient in situations when you need to produce a piece of callable code that needs to be used only once, e.g. in callbacks.

Note that the method does not have to be anonymous: you could make an equivalent named method. However, an since the anonymous method is built in the context of the method where it is used, the variables from the context are available to it. Your anonymous method assigns `SelectedMachine`, which is probably a property of your class. In the same way, anonymous methods can access local variables as well, which is a very powerful mechanism of combining together a state and a piece of code that operates on it.

Comment: Might the phrase "and therefore cannot be reused" be misleading?

Comment: @DanielPratt if I create a named delegate e.g `del customDelegate => a= a+b` then I could reuse customDelegate function.. is this right? so I guess a nameless function cannot be re-used whereas a named function can.

Comment: @jmesolomon I think Daniel meant that if you assign an anonymous function to a variable of delegate type and pass that variable around, you would be able to reuse that function by accessing it through a variable. Named methods can be reused both by name and through a delegate.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks for clearing that out. ^^,

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise. It is an Anonymous method using lambda expression.
the sign you are asking '=> { }' is called lambda expression.
Usually it is used with Delegate type like func, Action, predicate and others.
Have a look on the above types to make yourself more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It is a lambda expression. Have a look on this page for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx